# Get a random line from a text file in assets folder

Tags: java, android, c

I am currently trying to re-create a project from Python into Android Application. But I am currently stuck with something I don't literally know.

My Project is called "Passworder" (for generating German Passwords). And to make the password to generate **NOT** random letters, I want to generate words from "WordList.txt" from assets folder.

The Problem is, that I don't even know, how to generate random words. With minimalLength and replacementRule, then I can do it.

Some code from my **void**:

```js
    // GeneratedActivity
    private String generatePassword(int minLength, String charactersInBetween, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> replacementRule) {
        String wordList = FileUtil.readFile(getAssets() + "WordList.txt");
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < replacementRule.size(); i++) {
            output = output.replaceAll(replacementRule.get(i).get("replaceFrom").toString(), replacementRule.get(i).get("replaceTo").toString());
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    // FileUtil.readFile(String path)
    public static String readFile(String path) {
        createNewFile(path);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File(path));

            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = fr.read(buff)) > 0) {
                sb.append(new String(buff, 0, length));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fr != null) {
                try {
                    fr.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

*Yes, that code is even from that application "Sketchware"*

---

**EDIT (of my full GeneratedActivity.java)**

```js
package com.bechrisapps.passworder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bechrisapps.passworder.utility.FileUtil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class GeneratedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static int MINIMAL_LENGTH = 1;
    public static String CHARACTER_IN_BETWEEN = "";
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> REPLACEMENT_RULE = MainActivity.replacementRule;

    private String replaceFrom = "", replaceTo = "";

    private TextView textView;
    private Button btnGenerate, btnCopy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generated);
        initialize();
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        textView = findViewById(R.id.generated_password);
        btnGenerate = findViewById(R.id.generated_renew);
        btnCopy = findViewById(R.id.generated_copy);

        btnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("copiedPassword", textView.getText().toString());
                clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initializeLogic() {
        generatePassword(MINIMAL_LENGTH, CHARACTER_IN_BETWEEN, REPLACEMENT_RULE);
    }

    private String generatePassword(int minLength, String charactersInBetween, @NotNull ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> replacementRule) {
        String wordList = FileUtil.readFile(getAssets() + "WordList.txt");
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < replacementRule.size(); i++) {
            output = output.replaceAll(replacementRule.get(i).get("replaceFrom").toString(), replacementRule.get(i).get("replaceTo").toString());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

---

FileUtil.java

```js
package com.bechrisapps.passworder.utility;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class FileUtil {

    private static void createNewFile(String path) {
        int lastSep = path.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
        if (lastSep > 0) {
            String dirPath = path.substring(0, lastSep);
            makeDir(dirPath);
        }

        File file = new File(path);

        try {
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String readFile(String path) {
        createNewFile(path);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File(path));

            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = fr.read(buff)) > 0) {
                sb.append(new String(buff, 0, length));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fr != null) {
                try {
                    fr.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void writeFile(String path, String str) {
        createNewFile(path);
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;

        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(path), false);
            fileWriter.write(str);
            fileWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileWriter != null)
                    fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void copyFile(String sourcePath, String destPath) {
        if (!isExistFile(sourcePath)) return;
        createNewFile(destPath);

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath, false);

            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = fis.read(buff)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void moveFile(String sourcePath, String destPath) {
        copyFile(sourcePath, destPath);
        deleteFile(sourcePath);
    }

    public static void deleteFile(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);

        if (!file.exists()) return;

        if (file.isFile()) {
            file.delete();
            return;
        }

        File[] fileArr = file.listFiles();

        if (fileArr != null) {
            for (File subFile : fileArr) {
                if (subFile.isDirectory()) {
                    deleteFile(subFile.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                if (subFile.isFile()) {
                    subFile.delete();
                }
            }
        }

        file.delete();
    }

    public static boolean isExistFile(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        return file.exists();
    }

    public static void makeDir(String path) {
        if (!isExistFile(path)) {
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public static void listDir(String path, ArrayList<String> list) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists() || dir.isFile()) return;

        File[] listFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFiles == null || listFiles.length <= 0) return;

        if (list == null) return;
        list.clear();
        for (File file : listFiles) {
            list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    public static boolean isDirectory(String path) {
        if (!isExistFile(path)) return false;
        return new File(path).isDirectory();
    }

    public static boolean isFile(String path) {
        if (!isExistFile(path)) return false;
        return new File(path).isFile();
    }

    public static long getFileLength(String path) {
        if (!isExistFile(path)) return 0;
        return new File(path).length();
    }

    public static String getExternalStorageDir() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public static String getPackageDataDir(Context context) {
        return context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public static String getPackageObbDir() {
        return FileUtil.getExternalStorageDir() + "/Android/obb/com.theblacklistedgame.blacklisted";
    }

    public static String getPublicDir(String type) {
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type).getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public static String convertUriToFilePath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        String path = null;
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                }

                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris
                        .withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = uri.getPath();
        }

        if (path != null) {
            try {
                return URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        final String column = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
    private static String TAG = FileUtil.class.getName();
    private static String parentPath = "";

    public static boolean zip(String sourcePath, String destinationPath, String destinationFileName, Boolean includeParentFolder) {
        new File(destinationPath).mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
        try {
            if (!destinationPath.endsWith("/")) destinationPath += "/";
            String destination = destinationPath + destinationFileName;
            File file = new File(destination);
            if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));

            if (includeParentFolder)
                parentPath = new File(sourcePath).getParent() + "/";
            else
                parentPath = sourcePath;

            zipFile(zipOutputStream, sourcePath);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d(TAG, ioe.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (zipOutputStream != null)
                try {
                    zipOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return true;

    }

    private static void zipFile(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream, String sourcePath) throws IOException {

        File files = new File(sourcePath);
        File[] fileList = files.listFiles();

        String entryPath = "";
        BufferedInputStream input;
        for (File file : fileList) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                zipFile(zipOutputStream, file.getPath());
            } else {
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
                input = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream, BUFFER_SIZE);
                entryPath = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(parentPath, "");

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryPath);
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);

                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                    zipOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                input.close();
            }
        }


    }

    public static Boolean unzip(String sourceFile, String destinationFolder) {
        ZipInputStream zis = null;

        try {
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile)));
            ZipEntry ze;
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String fileName = ze.getName();
                fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("/") + 1);
                File file = new File(destinationFolder, fileName);
                File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();

                if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid path: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
                if (ze.isDirectory()) continue;
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                } finally {
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.d(TAG, ioe.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (zis != null)
                try {
                    zis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you explore [Java String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Java regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) API?

Comment: I tried that "String lines = wordList.split('\n')" Option, but to no avail.

Comment: Show the complete code which you have tried. Also, mention your requirement clearly e.g. a sample content from `WordList.txt`, sample input and sample output etc.

Comment: When it comes to "" WordList.txt ", I can say directly that this list has 1534 lines.

Comment: FWIW, here is [a complete working example of a diceware-style passphrase generator](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/DiceLight), written in Java, using a wordlist as an asset as the source of the words. Also, FWIW, here is [the same app written in Kotlin](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/DiceLight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is old, but I have the solution on who cannot progress with making passwords using a wordlist.

Obviously, first, read the file (can be from Storage or Assets) and test if that works. If this works, then create a random number picker and paste this following code:

```
public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

To get a random word out of the Wordlist, use

```
String[] lines = content.split(System.lineSeparator());
int random = getRandomNumber(0, lines.length);
String word = lines[random];
```

And to generate a new password, it is recommended to use `while` to loop, until it hits the minimal length (currentPassword is a String and I copied the code from my project ([see on my GitHub page](https://github.com/BeChris100/passworder-android)))

```
private void generateNewPassword() {
    currentPassword = "";

    while (currentPassword.length() <= minLength)
        currentPassword += lines[Utility.getRandomNumber(0, lines.length - 1)] + charsBetweenWords;

    if (replacesChars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFrom.size(); i++) {
            if (replacesCases) {
                String lowercase = listFrom.get(i).toLowerCase();
                String uppercase = listFrom.get(i).toUpperCase();

                currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll(lowercase, listTo.get(i));
                currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll(uppercase, listTo.get(i));
            } else {
                if (listTo.get(i).equals("$"))
                    currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll(listFrom.get(i), "\\$");
                else if (listFrom.get(i).equals("$"))
                    currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll("\\$", listTo.get(i));
                else if (listTo.get(i).equals("\\"))
                    currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll(listFrom.get(i), "\\");
                else if (listFrom.get(i).equals("\\"))
                    currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll("\\\\", listTo.get(i));
                else
                    currentPassword = currentPassword.replaceAll(listFrom.get(i), listTo.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    currentPassword = currentPassword.substring(0, currentPassword.length() - charsBetweenWords.length());

    passwordOutput.setText(currentPassword);
}
```